# How can I disable TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA without disabling others as well?

Tags: java, ssl, encryption

I'm trying to narrow down the allowed SSL ciphers for a java application.  In the java.security file, I am using:

> jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv2Hello, SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, 3DES_EDE_CBC, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256

Which produces the following allowed ciphers:

```
Will-Adams-MacBook-Air:~ Looker$ nmap -script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 9999 <AWS INSTANCE>.compute.amazonaws.com
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-09-06 14:23 PDT
Nmap scan report for <AWS INSTANCE>.compute.amazonaws.com
Host is up (0.079s latency).

PORT     STATE SERVICE
9999/tcp open  abyss
| ssl-enum-ciphers:
|   TLSv1.2:
|     ciphers:
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (dh 1024) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 1024) - A
|     compressors:
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: client
|     warnings:
|       Weak certificate signature: SHA1
|_  least strength: A

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 3.39 seconds
```

Great!  I'm almost there.  I want to also disallow `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA` but adding it to the `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms` disables everything:

```
Will-Adams-MacBook-Air:~ Looker$ nmap -script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 9999 <AWS INSTANCE>.compute.amazonaws.com
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-09-06 14:28 PDT
Nmap scan report for <AWS INSTANCE>.compute.amazonaws.com 
Host is up (0.079s latency).

PORT     STATE SERVICE
9999/tcp open  abyss

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.85 seconds
```

Why is this?  Is there a way for me to disable `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA` without also disabling `TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384`, `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384`, and `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384`?

Answer (score 1):

Starting from java 1.8.0_141 just [adding](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/288) `SHA1 jdkCA & usage TLSServer` to `jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms` should work.

> jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, MD5, RSA keySize < 1024,
>           DSA keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, SHA1 jdkCA & usage TLSServer

Alternatively,  just adding `SHA1` to `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms` should also work

> jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=MD5, SHA1, DSA, RSA keySize < 4096

You did not specified your JVM version, so let me know it this works for you please.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately adding `SHA1` to my `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms` is disallowing everything, and adding `SHA1 jdkCA & usage TLSServer' to the `jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms` seems to have no effect.

Running `javac -version` gives me `javac 1.8.0_131`

Comment: SHA-1 is disabled by default on [Java 1.8.0_141](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u141-relnotes-3720385.html) so updating could be a great starting point. Also, I would suggest: - to restore the original java.security and start from scratch, -check for exceptions on server side.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz: 8u141 disables SHA1 _signatures_ on _certificates_, not suites using SHA1 HMAC (also not protocol signatures, but TLS1.2 SigAlgs already fixed the protocol signatures). And it does so precisely _by_ changing jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms -- so updating to 8u141 does _exactly_ the same thing as editting the file in 8u131.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 so do you think my answer should work on 1.8.0_131? Also, as I could read `SHA1 jdkCA & usage TLSServer` was included on 8U141 so I don't think it could work on 131.

Answer (score 1):

**Works for me** to delete only that specific suite (as you wish) in Oracle 8u131 on Windows -- I don't have Mac, but JSSE is pure Java and should be the same on all platforms. `SHA1` *or* `HmacSHA1` to delete all Hmac-SHA1 suites also works for me. I *think*, but can't easily check, that lone `SHA1` in jdk.tls.disabled will also affect signatures and certs, which may not be desirable; certs are probably better handled by jdk.certpath.disabled instead.

The properties-file format is more complicated than it looks, and sometimes fragile. Make sure your edits are *exactly* as you posted -- especially no missing, added, or moved comma(s), no backslash or quotes, and no invisible characters like bidi or nbsp. You can put the line(s) you want to change in a separate file designated by *sysprop* `jdk.security.properties` (which can be set with `-D` on the commandline, unlike the other properties in `java.security`), to make it easier to edit and examine exactly.

Those said, if you (or someone) thinks this is increasing security, you're heading in the wrong direction. Though your nmap doesn't show it, removing RC4 from the jdk.tls.disabled value should enable RC4 suites and does on my system(s), and that's much more dangerous than any AES128 or HmacSHA1 suite ever. RSA-1024 is maybe billions of times worse, and so is DH-1024 (especially hardcoded/shared DH-1024 as JSSE uses) if you can find any client that doesn't prefer ECDHE (where P-256 is okay -- unless you are a tinfoil-hatter in which case it is even worse). And as nmap told you, a cert signed with SHA1 is awful -- unless it is your root or anchor (so the signature doesn't actually matter for security), or at least a totally private CA that will always and forever only accept requests from people thoroughly known to be good and competent and never make mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Just add cipher suites to jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms to disable it.
Like

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, DH, DHE, \
EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL, RSA keySize < 512, DESede, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
```